# Chrome Extensions programming - cancelling a form submit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which is just a simple form with two input fields and a submit button. The problem I encountered is that something like this:

```
  $('#submit').submit(function() {
    $('#word').val('')
    $('#translation').val('')
    return false
  })
```

Still reloads the popup.html (e.g. submits the form)! I was forced to change the type of the submit button to just 'button' and use

```
  $('#submit').live('click', function(e) {
    $('#word').val('')
    $('#translation').val('')
  })
```

This works, but now (of course) the ENTER doesn't work for form 'submission'... and I feel this is a hack when the original prevention of reload by returning false should work...

Anyone else had such a problem?

Comment: That looks correct.  If you could reproduce this in jsfiddle.net, I could help out more.

Answer (score 2):

The `.submit()` is an event on the form, not on the submit button.

I.E.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from the onsubmit event of the form.

```
 $('#YOUR_FORM_ID').submit(function() {
    $('#word').val('')
    $('#translation').val('')
    return false
  })
```

Comment: Still it was acting buggy, so I decided to use the regular Button instead of Submit .. I then hooked up events that catch ENTER to simulate posting the form and other things.